# alphanumeric and special character sorting

Tags: sql, database, sorting, standards, alphanumeric

I wanted to know the different standards of sorting. To be more specific take the sample set:

(Please note there's capitals, small letters, special characters, null values and numbers here)

- A
- a
- 3F
- Zx
- -
- 1Ad
- NULL

How would the Oracle Database sort this by default?

How would LINQ sort this by default?

How would db2 sort this by default?

*(the following may get even more vague)*

How does the Windows platform sort this? (I mean say you have a couple of filenames, by default how would this get treated in a name sort)

How does the *nix platform sort this?

Is there some sort of standard for alphanumeric/special character sorting? The Windows operating system orders with numbers first, then alphabets. The Oracle database however treats alphabets first. I'm not sure of the *nix platform.

It would be nice to have one place to know all these rules for the most common platforms (listed in questions above). Would the gurus throw some light on this topic?

Cheers,
K

Answer (score 2):

Sorting in SQL databases is controlled by the collating sequence. You can search your docs for "collation". Depending on your dbms (and, probably, on its age), the collation might be a database-, table-, or column-level setting.

Here's a link to [a chart of SQL Server 2008 collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx).

Most modern SQL dbms platforms will let you override the existing collation at run time. For example, you can specify the collation you want to be used for sorting in the ORDER BY clause of a SQL statement. Here's the syntax for an [ORDER BY . . .  COLLATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 (Transact-SQL).